# reactjs services and presentation components splitted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns, service, components

I am giving my first steps into reactjs.  I created a service to [the movie db API](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api) using fetch. I already accomplish to list the name of the movies.

What I am trying to do is have a completly independent components. One component to connect to the API and other component be responsible to present that info.

Right now what I have both of this behaviours in the same component :(

Can anyone help me?

Here's my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const listUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/4/list/5?api_key=a6ebd775daadc2ec23c371e873e20a02&page=1';

class ListingService extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(listUrl)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error('Network request failed');
        }
        return response;
      })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          movieName: response.results.map((movie) => {
            return (
              <li key={movie.id}>{movie.title}</li>
            );
          }),
        });
      }, () => {
        this.setState({
          requestFailed: true,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.requestFailed) return <p>Failed!</p>;
    if (!this.state.movieName) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2><ol>{this.state.movieName}</ol></h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have a father component with this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ListingService from '../../services/listing/index';


const List = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <b>List of movies</b>
      <ListingService />
    </div>
  );
};

export default List;
```

Should I use redux to this?

Comment: you don't need redux. the most basic thing you can do it just make another component from what `ListingService` renders, then pass its state as props to the new component. is that not what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best thing to do would be to make a MovieList Component, from your ListingService you would pass it a prop of movies.

```
<MovieList movies={this.state.movieName}
```

rather than saving the movie names in your ajax call as jsx, just save them as strings in an array.

In your MovieList component, map thru the array of movies

```
const MovieList = props => ( props.movies.map( (movie,i) => ( <ol><li key={i} >{movie.title}</li></ol> ) )
```

This is a basic implementation, but you could expand it to make the list of movies objects so you can save the id and make the key more specific.

Comment: Thanks it work. 
Still I have the father component that it is just calling ListingService. I was thinking if threre's a way I could use this father component to display the list of movies. Does it make sense?

Comment: You would ultimately refactor List to be Listing Service. Your smart components will hold all of the logic, and your presentation components are the children which display the logic. So Listing Service is the smart, MovieList is the presentation child

Comment: Thanks, great explanation :) I got it